# Asp.Net Core MVC получение списка enum в html

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Всем привет!
Делаю калькулятор Asp.Net Core MVC.
Имеется модель в которой присутствует enum список. Как мне получить данные из enum и поместить их в отдельные кнопки в представлении?
К примеру должна быть кнопка `Addition`,  `Substruction` и так далее.

```
namespace MyWeb.Models
{
    public class CalcModel  
    {
        [DisplayName("First number")]
        public double lhsOperand { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Second number")]
        public double rhsOperand { set; get; }
        public double Result { get; set; }

        public CalculationMethod calculationMethod { get; set; }
        public enum CalculationMethod
        {
            Addition = '+',
            Substraction = '-',
            Multiplication ='*',
            Division = '/'
        }
    }
}
```

Так же вот моё представление:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="card-body">
    <form asp-controller="Calc" asp-action="IndexCalculator" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lhsOperand">First numbers:</label>
            <input type="number" asp-for="lhsOperand" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rhsOperand">Second numbers:</label>
            <input type="number" asp-for="rhsOperand" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Result" asp-for="Result">Result</label>
        </div>
        
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">=</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Получение всех значений из енама:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(CalculationMethod))
    .Cast<CalculationMethod>()
    .Select(e => new { Name = e.ToString("G"), Symbol = (char) e })
```

Demo https://dotnetfiddle.net/3apApT

Далее просто делаете перебор и генерите кнопки.

P.S я настоятельно советую подготовить все данные в контроллере